# How to access EC2 instance using its public IP via curl command? EC2 created via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

I have created an EC2 instance and security group resource via Terraform file. However when I do,

```
curl  http://<public IP>:8080
```

I get
**curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 8080 after 8 ms: Couldn't connect to server**

Here is the tf file. How to fix this so I can access EC2 instance via the curl command?

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

variable "server_port"{
  type = number
  description = "the port for HTTP"
  default = 8080
}
resource "aws_instance" "name" {
  ami = "ami-0dfb78957e4edea0c"
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              nohup busybox httpd -f -p {var.server_port} &
              EOF
  
  user_data_replace_on_change = true

  tags={
    Name="terraform-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance"{
  name="terraform-example-security-instance"
  ingress {
       from_port = var.server_port
    to_port = var.server_port
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
   egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
  tags={
    Name="terraform-example"
  }
} 

output "public_ip" {
    value = aws_instance.name.public_ip
    description ="The public IP address of EC2"
}
```

Comment: Did you check if your "Hello, World" is even working on localhost on the instance?

Comment: You seem to be missing a dollar sign in front of `{var.server_port}`

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the terraform code or the way you craeted your instance. All your configurations are correct.
Check the actual server you are running inside the instance to check if it is running and accessible locally.

Answer (score 0):

This needed egress set too. It is working now with this updated code.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}

variable "server_port"{
  type = number
  description = "the port for HTTP"
  default = 8082
}
resource "aws_instance" "name" {
  ami = "ami-0310483fb2b488153"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.instance.id]
  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash
              echo "Hello, World" > index.html
              sudo busybox httpd -f -p ${var.server_port} &
              EOF
  
  user_data_replace_on_change = true

  tags={
    Name="terraform-example"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "instance"{
  name="terraform-example-security-instance"
  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port = 443
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = var.server_port
    to_port = var.server_port
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags={
    Name="terraform-example"
  }
} 

output "public_ip" {
    value = aws_instance.name.public_ip
    description ="The public IP address of EC2"
}
```